proof of two simple left R module must be isomorphic
Theorem:
If $R$ is simple left artinian,then any two simple left $R$ module is isomorphic.
pf:
since $R$ is simple left artinian, so by Wedderburn artin theorem, it is isomorphic to the matrix algebra $M_n(D)$ for some division ring, then $R$ is also semisimple left artinian since for semisimple left artinian,it can decompose into prduct of simple ideals, so in particular, $R$ is also semisimple left artinian, also we know that for $R$ is semisimple left artinian, every simple legt R module is isomorphic to a minimal left ideal of $R$, but $R$ is matrix algbra, so minimal left ideal is only column, but all column is isomorphic, so we get all simple left $R$ module is isomorphic.
Does this proof right?

Up to the point you say that every simple left ideal is a submodule of $R$ you are correct, but you have a gap after that.
I am speaking of "so minimal left ideal is only column."  It is not true that the only minimal left ideals are the "column" left ideals of the form $Re_{ii}$, where $e_{ii}$ is the unit matrix that is $1$ only on the $i,i$ position. For example there is also $R(e_{11}+e_{12})$, which is also simple, but not a single-column left ideal.
But it is true that the single-column ideals are all mutually isomorphic, and furthermore, that all simple left modules are mutually isomorphic.
To see this, suppose that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are nonisomorphic minimal left ideals.  For every $a\in S_1$, $S_2a$ is a left submodule of $S_1$.
If $S_2a=S_1$, then the mapping $x\mapsto xa$ is a homomorphism $S_2\to S_1$ which would necessarily be an isomorphism, and this brings us to a contradiction.  We are forced to concede that $S_2a=\{0\}$ for every $a\in S_1$.
But now look at what we have: $S_1S_1=\{0\}$, which means that the left annihilator of $S_1$ in $R$ (which is a two-sided ideal) is nonzero. The only nonzero two-sided ideal is $R$, and the annihilator of $S_1$ can't be all of $R$, so we have a contradiction.
The resolution is that all simple left ideals of $R$ are mutually isomorphic, and hence all simple left $R$ modules are mutually isomorphic.

I think you mean non isomorphic minimal left ideal.

@lee I think I guessed the line your comment pertains to and corrected it. But you'll have to let me know if I got it.

Why $S_2a$ is a left submodule of$S_2$,it is not a  subset since it is not a right module. I think I can think it another way.Since R is semi simple left Arminian, we can decompose it into simple component $I_1,I_2…$ where all be simple ideal, but R is simple,so  only one simple component, also the number of non isomorphic simple  left R module is the same as the number of component of R which is  only one, so  all simple left R module are isomorphic ,and we are done.

@lee You're right, I did have an indexing error, which I have now corrected.

@lee Check again. $Re_{11}$ is not a subset of $R(e_{11}+e_{12})$.
